# Concatenate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor, concatenation

I using javascript for concatenate two columns that I have in an table:

```js
var ruta = document.getElementById('ruta1').innerHTML;
    var desborde = document.getElementById('desborde1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('concatenate').innerHTML += '' + ruta + '' + desborde;
```

```html
<table id="Enrut_calx" class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Ruta 1</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Desborde 1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>                    
                        <td class="text-center" id="ruta1">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RUTA_1)
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="desborde1">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESBORDE_1)
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="concatenate">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESBORDES)
                        </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

My result is:

[image]

However, although the result that it shows me in the image is what I require, in the other rows it does not show me the same result and it makes the rows blank.

Which if someone could guide me I would appreciate it.

Comment: You cannot give the same `id` value to more than one element if you expect page code to work. Give the elements `class` values instead.

Comment: JavaScript only allows one element with the same id. Why are you using JavaScript to combine it and not using the templating language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify exactly why you're using Javascript, and the syntax you're using makes me believe you are using Blazor.

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems easier to do it something like below, no need for JavaScript when Blazor can do all of that for you. This is a core use case for why Blazor and Razor syntax exists.

```
<table id="Enrut_calx" class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Ruta 1</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Desborde 1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>                    
                        <td class="text-center" id="ruta1">
                            @item.RUTA_1
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="desborde1">
                            @item.DESBORDE_1
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" id="concatenate">
                            @(item.RUTA_1 + " " +  item.DESBORDE_1)
                        </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                }
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Kevon, Basically my goal is to be able to concatenate the two columns, but when doing it in javascript it only showed me the result in a single row. When reviewing your comment, I did it as in your example, only I put it in parentheses and now I get what I wanted. Thank you for your comments and for the example, it helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: According to your example, just modify a part as follows: 
<td class="text-center">
    @(item.RUTA_1 + " " + item.DESBORDE_1)
</td>

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I edited the example. You are right, I didn't test my code. It'll be super helpful to everyone if you can accept this as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but you have "harcoded" IDs in your rows inside your foreach loop.

So that loop will generate a lot of DOM objects with the same ID (ruta1, desborde1, and concatenate), and when you try to do "document.getElementById('ruta1')" you not longer find one element, you'll find a lot of elements with the same ID (which shouldn't happen).

So my advice here would be, update this part:

```
   <td class="text-center" id="ruta1">
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RUTA_1)
   </td>
   <td class="text-center" id="desborde1">
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESBORDE_1)
   </td>
   <td class="text-center" id="concatenate">
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESBORDES)
   </td>
```

to generate different IDs for each column, something like ruta1_1, ruta1_2, ruta1_3 using the index at the end. (Repeat the same logic for desborde1, and concatenate)

Comment: Hello Facundo, I already changed the names of the IDs, but it marks the result in the first row and the others are still blank :(

Comment: And did you update the javascript code? You should be doing a loop in there too

Right now your just assigning the value of ONE field, you should do the same for each row

Comment: Hello facuendo, change the name of the IDs, assigning names with and for example: value1_1, etc, just as the javascript makes the change, however the problem still persists.

Comment: Huh, that is weird, can you open the developer tools while you're executing your program? (If you're using Chrome, you just need to press F12) you can see a console there, are you getting any errors?